# Where should environment-specific values be saved in a Laravel 5 application?

Tags: git, configuration, docker, laravel-5

I'm trying to wrap my head around the `.env` way of doing configuration in Laravel 5.

Here's my story: I'm converting an existing Laravel 4 application to Laravel 5. I currently have different environments (`local` and `production`) and the cascading configuration system works nicely. I have my environment-specific application config in separate folders under `app/config`.

My application is currently deployed (and developed) in a Docker container. To build for deployment, I use a Dockerfile to build my application image (based on my `master` branch), which is then pushed to a repository and pulled on the production server.

So now I'm trying to convert my configuration for Laravel 5 and I'm a little confused. Everything I read says you add your `.env` files to the `.gitignore` file so it's not included in your repository. I understand the security reasons for this - don't commit sensitive API keys/passwords/whatever to your repository. But I'm not sure how to ensure that my production `.env` file is included in my build step if it's not part of the repository.

The idea I had was to place my production `.env` file somewhere in my file system outside of my development environment, and then copy it when it's needed.

Is this the "best practice" for managing this? Is this how others do it?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK you are meant to copy the file onto the server directly. I've been SSHing into my server and updating the env file as necessary to reflect new changes / requirements.

Comment: @JamesSpence Yeah, that's what I thought too, but my build/deploy step is a little different - it's not easy or convenient to build the Docker image, deploy it, THEN ssh into the server, enter the Docker container, & copy a file. That's why I thought it important to mention the fact that I'm doing this with Docker.

Comment: I've never used Docker before, but I assume you can copy files into that environment, right? It might not be as simple as pulling the repo in and going right ahead, but it's just another step. It's what I have to do to deploy my env files.

Comment: Yes, but... the recommended way to do it is initially when you build the image. You *can* set up your containers so that you can access the file system later, but it's not the best way to do things, since Docker is all about isolation.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my lack of knowledge of the ins and outs of Docker limit my ability to answer well, but I'll brainstorm with you at least :) does Docker have any way of passing variables before building the image, a la vagrant? Maybe you can tell it to load the .env file and pass it to the image being built, so the file gets created.

Comment: please refer to the https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#env section on docker for setting env entries on deploy

Answer (score 2):

.env file will contain the variables which you will apply using env('variable') in the config files. The best practice would be set any parameters that are environment independent (meaning that will work on both production and develop) right in the config files and set any environment dependent variables in the .env file

Example: on your dev and staging server you will send email  using gmail smtp but on production server you will use your own smtp server. Simply set the email configuration as follows:

config file:

```
return [
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT'),
    'from' => ['address' => env('MAIL_FROM_EMAIL'), 'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME')],
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false
];
```

.env on dev and staging

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_FROM_EMAIL=email@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=email@gmail.com
MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
```

.env on production

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.domain.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_FROM_EMAIL=noreply@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=noreply@domain.com
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
```

never include the .env file on your git repo. Instead make a copy and name it ".env.sample" and add that. So your dev team can setup their own .env file once the repo is cloned. You will need to add .env to the .gitignore to prevent it from adding to the repo.